NetCDF format not recognized for import into QGIS (Mac) v. 3.38
I am having trouble importing NetCDF files into QGIS on the Mac platform.  I am running the latest version of QGIS installed through Macports to get maximum performance with an M1 processor vs the Rosetta emulated version.  Not sure if this could be the problem.
I have tried importing various NetCDF files from different sites and they are not recognized as either raster or mesh layers.   I keep getting "the format is not a valid or  recognized data source" error.   If anyone can give some insights I would be greatly appreciative.  I have looked and looked online but cannot find a solution.
Below are all the versions of the associated QGIS packages installed if this helps.
QGIS version
3.38.0-Grenoble
QGIS code branch
Release 3.38
Qt version
5.15.12
Python version
3.12.4
GDAL/OGR version
3.9.0
PROJ version
9.4.1
EPSG Registry database version
v11.006 (2024-03-13)
GEOS version
3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
SQLite version
3.46.0
PDAL version
2.7.1
PostgreSQL client version
unknown
SpatiaLite version
5.1.0
QWT version
6.1.6
QScintilla2 version
2.13.3
OS version
macOS 14.5

Here is some additional information. Sometimes when I launch QGIS I get this error, which I believe is a Python error.  It does not happen every time I launch QGIS, just once in awhile.  I don't know if this has anything to do with NetCDF incompatibility.  Just wanted to give some additional information.
An error occurred during execution of following code:
faulthandler.enable(file=qgis.utils._qgis_fault_handler_file)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ''', line 1, in
PermissionError: [Errno 1l Operation not permitted

Python version:
3.12.4 (main, Jun 8 2024, 04:51:36) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)]
QGIS version:
3.38.0-Grenoble 'Grenoble', exported


Do you mean that the same NetCDF files can be opened on Windows and Linux? Can you show where to get some test data?

The QGIS community on Substack was able to resolve this issue for me.  The Macports port of QGIS did not include the NetCDF file support so this had to be added.   It believe they will update the port to in the future to include this file format.   So, yes, the file should probably work on Windows and Linux provided they have GDAL installed with NetCDF support along with QGIS.   If one already has GDAL installed but not sure what variants including NetCDF are supported they can: port variants gdal and if NetCDF is not seen enter sudo port install gdal +netcdf  This fixed the issue for me.
